# Stripe API: Can we Update single upcoming invoice of a subscription in stripe?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

So, I've created a subscription on stripe using:

```
stripe.subscriptions.create
```

Is there a way to update the single upcoming invoice ?

I want to update the payment_date i.e. due_at of that upcoming invoice.

For example:

if its May 10, I want to shift this to 01 May.

I tried looking in the docs but couldn't find anything related to this issue.

Any solution or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using `collection_method: "send_invoice"` when creating the subscription? If so, there are two places where you can set the due date for an invoice:

- Set it when creating the subscription with [`days_until_due`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-days_until_due).
- Or set it on the invoice directly. All invoices are created in `draft` status for one hour, so you have the time to edit them if needed. You could listen to the webhook event [`invoice.created`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.created), and then update the [`days_until_due`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update#update_invoice-days_until_due) or [`due_date`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/update#update_invoice-due_date) of the invoice.

Comment: No, its charge automatically.
The user has already paid 1 invoice.
For the second invoice i'm trying to update the date

Comment: With `charge_automatically` subscriptions, the invoice is paid automatically when it is finalized. It's only possible to update `days_until_due` or `due_date` for `send_invoice` subscriptions. The only option would be to change the billing cycle of the subscription, [as explained here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#changing).